# Is this a MSVC++ compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I think I might have found a compiler bug in the MSVC++ compiler that comes with VS2013, but it's such a simple case I can't be sure. Coupled with the fact that I'm still learning C++ I wanted to ask here before I submit anything; because honestly I'm pretty sure it'll just be something I'm doing wrong resulting in an unusual error message.

Anyway, I reduced the problem in to a small test file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::wstring cstr_to_wstring(const char* cString) {
    std::string temp = cString;
    return { temp.begin(), temp.end() };
}

int main() {
    std::cout << cstr_to_wstring("Hi").c_str();
}
```

When I try to compile that, I get the following error:

```
1>d:\documents\projects\compilerbugtest\compilerbugtest\compilerbugtest.cpp(6): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 227)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
```

To work around the problem I can just specify the type on line six, so that:

`return { temp.begin(), temp.end() };`

becomes

`return std::wstring { temp.begin(), temp.end() };`.

Is this really a compiler bug? Thank you.

Comment: I'd say `An internal error in the compiler` is always worth reporting regardless of source code used.

Comment: When the compiler states, that this is a compiler bug, then it's a bug in the compiler or it's a bug to state, that it is a bug in the compiler. In both cases, it's a compiler bug :-)

Comment: Haha, good points, GSerg and Torsten... :)

Comment: Your code successfully compiled with `g++ (Debian 4.8.2-14) 4.8.2`.  However when `c_str()` returned `const wchar_t *`, `cout` printed the address value in hex.

Comment: @nodakai Ah well, like I said, I'm really a C++ noob, haha. I just used the first function I found that would make it compile :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug in the compiler.  All compiler crashes are compiler bugs, regardless whether the code is well-formed.  This particular bug was reported on Microsoft Connect in November:

> [Internal compiler error with std::map operations and braces in return statement.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808852/internal-compiler-error-with-std-map-operations-and-braces-in-return-statement)

In the bug, Xiang reports that we have fixed this issue for the next major release of the compiler (and I've verified that your code compiles using the latest internal build).  In the meantime, the recommended workaround is to do what you've done and name the type in the return statement.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply. :) I already raised a bug on MS Connect after the comments left here encouraged me; so I guess it ought to be marked as a duplicate. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814718/msvc-compiler-error

Comment: Thanks.  We'll resolve it as a duplicate.  It's better that a bug is reported multiple times than not at all.  :-)

Comment: I am reading on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808852/internal-compiler-error-with-std-map-operations-and-braces-in-return-statement and it should be fixed but I still having the same issue.

Comment: @MiguelAngel I've just now verified that the program in the original question compiles successfully with Visual C++ 2015.  Do you have a similar program that does not compile successfully with Visual C++ 2015?  If so, please open a new bug on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I am trying exactly the same program. I am updating VS2013 to update 5, I will send a report in case of the error still existing after the update. thanks!

Comment: @MiguelAngel This was fixed in Visual Studio 2015.  The fix was not backported to any Visual Studio 2013 update.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis well, after update 5 it is compiling well. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808852/internal-compiler-error-with-std-map-operations-and-braces-in-return-statement tells this fix was included on VS 2013 update 2.